# How can I use a filter and hood with my Nikon L820?

Tags: nikon, lens-hood, filter-diameter

I'm very new to the photography and don't have much knowledge. I have a Nikon L820 and want to add a hood and filter to it, however I don't know if it can be added directly, or what's the 'mm' rating of the lens thread might be.

Comment: tell us all the 'funny numbers' printed on the very front of the lens please.

Answer (score 3):

the camera that you own, the Nikon L820 is a bridge /semi-pro camera. and there is no lens thread on the edge of your lens. so you can not fix an filter or a hood on your camera's lens (very unfortunate).

however you can make your own lens hood and fix it :p ,

materials required:

1. Paper cup / plastic cup
2. Blade/cutter

Procedure:

1. measure the diameter of your lens 
   [image]
2. Get a Paper cup and make a hole at the base of the cup with the same measurement as the diameter of your lens
   [image]
3. Now combine the camera with the hood.fix on your lense and shoot away.

   Behold the DIY lens hood.

enjoy mate. happy clicking .

Comment: The trick to this kind of makeshift hood is to watch out for vignetting. This hood doesn't account for the angle of view of the lens so the photographer is responsible for making sure it's not interfering.

Answer (score 2):

A little searching shows that a company called Kiwifotos put together a hood and filter adapter kit. Should be just what you need; uses 62mm filters: http://www.ebay.com/itm/LENS-ADAPTER-FILTER-SET-NIKON-COOLPIX-L820-62MM-KIT-/330904438399